# How to "view as" iOS 6.1 and earlier in Xcode 8?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, xib, xcode8

In the new Xcode in "Identity and Type" tab "Interface Builder Document" section there is no more the option to view Xib in older style.. "View as: iOS 6.1 and Earlier"... is there a way to still use this option or they just removed it?
Here an example of what is missing now:
[image]

Comment: I'm curious what you think you would see if you had this option.

Comment: I don't think, I know what I see... I see the view with iOS 6 style

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Comment: "I see the view with iOS 6 style" You mean that things like rounded rect buttons come back?

Comment: Yes but also the top Navigation Bar goes down 20 pxls